# x86 Assembly (NASM) Decimal > Octal

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
asm_main:
enter   0,0               ; setup routine
pusha
call read_int
    mov ebx,eax
func:
    mov ecx,ebx
    shl ecx,29
    shr ecx,29
    mov eax,ecx
    call print_int
    shr ebx,3
    cmp ebx,0
    ja func
    jmp fin

fin:
    call print_nl
    popa
    mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
    leave
    ret
```

Im trying to understand this piece of code.

I see it converts a decimal to octal and prints the octal value in inverted order. What i dont get is the part where ecx is first shifted by 29 bits to the left and then shifted back.. if i understand it right 4 bits are lost due to the operation but how does this contribute to calculating the octal value.

Comment: It's 3 bits not 4, and they are not lost, they are the ones that stay. The top 29 are zeroed (aka. "lost"). Could have been written as `and ecx, 7` which would have been better in every respect. Remember that `2^3=8` hence that is the least significant octal digit.

Comment: It is not a decimal conversion, but binary to octal, three bits at a time. First the 3 l.s. bits of `ebx`, then `ebx` is shifted right by 3 bits, and so on. The m.s. 29 bits of `ecx` are not lost, simply not needed. They are still there in `ebx`, being shifted to the right, 3 bits per octal digit.

Comment: The `call read_int` subroutine did already convert the decimal into binary for you, the remaining code is converting binary into octal. Would it convert truly decimal (like string or BCD encoded) into octal, it would be lot more complicated code.